# How can I Cut and Paste PivotTable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a PevoteTable in data source worksheet, So I want move that PivotTable in appropriate situation.

What is a PivotTable Range for using code `Sheets("SheetName").Range("PivotTableRange").Cut` or what is the better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TableRange2` object of the `PivotTable`, see step-by-step code below:

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtRng As Range

' set the Sheet object where the Pivot Table lies
Set Sht = Worksheets("SheetName")

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = Sht.PivotTables("PivotTableName")

' set the Pivot-Table range you want to copy
Set PvtRng = PvtTbl.TableRange2

' copy the Range
PvtRng.Copy
```